# How to use Apache Ignite Rest api With Java in Eclips

Tags: datagrid, ignite, in-memory-database, gridgain

Can any one explain How to use Apache Ignite Rest API With Java in Eclipse with example?What the jetty server and its use in Apache ignite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignite starts Jetty server internally to serve your requests. You should provide provide Jetty XML [1] and set it to `ConnectorConfiguration.jettyPath` path property. Please refer to docs for more information [2].

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api#section-sample-jetty-xml-configuration
[2] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api#section-general-configuration